# Input border style ie8 vs ie10

Tags: css

I've seen that in ie10, input's default style is solid, as opposed to ie8 where it has a 3D shadow in the top and left borders.

[image]

In order to fix this, I added a border-style:inset to the input, and now inputs look alike in both ie8 and ie10.

[image]

However, the problem now is that when I zoom out, dropdown elements have a darker border-top than inputs.

[image]

Here's pretty much what I mean: [jsfiddle](http://tinyurl.com/lnw7z78)

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with some [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) or [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Comment: @Vucko Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, no luck

Answer (score 1):

Make `border:none;` and then apply border separately.

**For Instance,**

```
input [type="text"]{border:none; border:1px solid gray;}
```

This will make border to be uniform across all IE versions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The problem is not the border itself, but how it is displayed when zooming out. I tried setting border none first, but the behaviour didn't change