# IE8 Border vs IE10 border for table

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

I am having problem regarding the border of table. I tried searching but got nothing except [input-border-style-ie8-vs-ie10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352309/input-border-style-ie8-vs-ie10)

It does not work for me. The border in IE 8 are like some kind of 3D shadow but in IE 10 it changes to lines. I want same look of IE 8 in IE 10 . Please help me if someone has faced same and has some solution or provide some way to do make it same in both browsers.

How it look like in IE 8
[image]

How it look like in IE 10 [image]

Ignore the color showing in IE8 picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is not working as per my requirement ,so for now i am using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
```

so that i can have same view in IE10 as i have in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet, try looking into using a shiv: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv

Comment: Hi Andy it`s not working, can you show me a sample if you have tried ?